# Django email attachment issue

Tags: django, email, attachment

I have a form model:

```
class ManuscriptForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Your Name')
    sender = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email')
    attach  = forms.Field(label='Attach Your Manuscript', widget = forms.FileInput, required=False) # upload field!
    subject = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

and a view:

```
def manuscript_form(request):
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = ManuscriptForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
        attach = request.FILES['attach']
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']

        recipients = ['info@example.com']
        if cc_myself:
            recipients.append(sender)

        from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage
        mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, sender, recipients)
        mail.attach(attach.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
        mail.send()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
else:
    form = ManuscriptForm() # An unbound form

return render_to_response('manuscript_form.html', {
    'form': form,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The problem is I keep getting a:`"Key 'attach' not found in <MultiValueDict: {}>"` error. With attachment capability taken out, all works fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

replace the `attach = request.FILES['attach']` with `attach = request.FILES.get('attach')` so that the variable `attach` will be `None` when no files are "attached" by the user.

When you do `request.FILES['attach']` you're assuming that the key is present, which might have been caught by your form error checker, except that the field is not `required`.

Comment: don't you need to do `request.FILES.get('attach', None)` ? won't it throw an exception with just `request.FILES.get('attach')`

Comment: James Khoury: no `get` defaults to `None`

Comment: @rm I tried with get, but now throws a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'` error. Seems to me that `request.Files` is not being passed `'attach'` value, but I have no clue why. The html output definitely contains `<input type="file" name="attach" id="id_attach" />`.Not sure what to try now.

Comment: Actually, no the POST is receiving the attachment according to Django errors, but as a variable, not as a file.

Comment: (1) if `attach` is `None` you can't do `attach.name`, right? (2) what do you mean "no the POST is receiving the attachment according to Django errors, but as a variable"?

Comment: ok. My error. I had omitted the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from my form so that no `request.FILE` data was being passed. Sorry. At least maybe this will help someone else spot the same mistake. Thanks for the input.